# Vows with Async nested topics - scope problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, vows

I want my vow to have access to outerDocs and innerDocs from my topics but it doesn't.

```
'ASYNC TOPIC': {
  topic: function() {
    aModel.find({}, this.callback);
  },
  'NESTED ASYNC TOPIC': {
    topic: function(outerDocs) {
      anotherModel.find({}, this.callback(null, innerDocs, outerDocs));
    },
    'SHOULD HAVE ACCESS TO BOTH SETS OF DOCS': function(err, innerDocs, outerDocs) {
      console.log(err, innerDocs, outerDocs);
      return assert.equal(1, 1);
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`: For one, you tagged this question as a Java question, something it is not. You understand that Java and Javascript are as closely related as ham is to hamster.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set arguments to the callback like that, the find function will do that itself.  Do this instead:

```
topic: function(outerDocs) {
  var self = this;
  anotherModel.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    self.callback(err, docs, outerDocs);
  });
},
```

Comment: Thought this would work when I read it but Vows doesn't seem to support handling the callback that way. (Test just bombs without an error message.) There are sync examples in the docs that are similar (add args to this.callback etc) but the sync examples don't seem to manipulate callback's arguments directly. Not sure why.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, you can get around this problem by using ECMA 5's bind method. So you can do: anotherModel.find({}, this.callback.bind(this, null, outerDocs) and then in your vow: function (_, outerDocs, err, innerDocs) etc. Bind prepends the additional arguments so they have to go at the beginning.

Comment: I think you're running into a different problem if your test is just bombing without an error message.  I use this specific pattern all over my codebase without any crashes.